# Can't install mailutils Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, mail, mailutils

It seems like I can't install `mailutils` in Ubuntu 18.04. It's a dependency error and I can't find about this issue also somewhere else.

**Command:** `sudo apt install mailutils`

**Output:**

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mailutils : Depends: guile-2.0-libs but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libmailutils5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then I ran this:
`sudo apt install guile-2.0-libs`

**Output:**

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 guile-2.0-libs : Depends: libgc1c2 (>= 1:7.2d) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libltdl7 (>= 2.4.6) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried installing `libgc1c2` mannualy:
`sudo apt install libgc1c2`

**Output:**

```
Reading state information... Done
Package libgc1c2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libgc1c2' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Do you have [universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/q/148638) added/enabled?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing dependencie  [guile-2.0-libs](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/guile-2.0-libs) available from the `main` repository. [`mailutils`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/fr/bionic/mailutils) and its dependency [`libmailutils5`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libmailutils5) are available from `universe`, edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` as follows:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mailutils
```